# How to set a welcome channel discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a public moderation bot with a welcome message, but how can i make people set their welcome channel?
I have this but this doesn't work, it says it sets the channel but if someone joins theres no actual message. Can someone help me with this? This is my code:

````
async def on_member_join(member):
    global welcome_channel_dict
    channel_id = welcome_channel_dict[member.guild.id]
    await client.get_channel(channel_id).send(f'{member.mention} welcome to the Otay! Support server! Enjoy your stay!')

@client.command(name='welcome')
async def set_welcome_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    global welcome_channel_dict
    welcome_channel_dict[ctx.guild.id] = channel.id
    await ctx.send(f'Sent welcome channel for {ctx.message.guild.name} to {channel.name}')```
````

Comment: Are you receiving the on_member_join event? I think you have to [enable the `Server Members` Intent in the developer portal](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Comment: I did that and it still doesn’t work

Comment: I just tested your code with my bot, and it's working just fine. if this is your exact code, just make sure you add `@client.event` over `on_member_join`.

Comment: Oops, i forgot to copy the @client.event at the top. But it still doesnt work for me i tried it with welcome_channel_dict = {} at top beginning of my script and without and it doesnt work

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What error are you getting? You have to define `welcome_channel_dict` before your command can look for the global variable. Also if you're defining the dict in the code itself, and then adding the info it will erase all info every time you restart the bot. So try storing the info in a separate JSON file and looking up/adding info to that instead

Comment: I'm not getting any error, the part where people can set their welcome channel works, but the message just doesn't send. do you know where i can find a tutorial on something like that on storing the info in a json file?

Comment: [Here's](https://realpython.com/python-json/) a thorough tutorial on JSON in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you enabled the intents in the developer portal, did you remember to define intents in the bot code? you need set:

```py
import json

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'your_prefix', intents = intents)
```

Cloud provided a very good tutorial for the JSON. You can do something like this in your code so that the dict doesn't reset whenever your bot resets.

Create a 'guilds.json' file in your root directory. open that dict and simply add `{}` and you're ready to go.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)

    channel_id = guilds_dict[str(member.guild.id)]
    await client.get_channel(int(channel_id)).send(f'{member.mention} welcome to the Otay! Support server! Enjoy your stay!')


@client.command(name='welcome')
async def set_welcome_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    with open('guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)

    guilds_dict[str(ctx.guild.id)] = str(channel.id)
    with open('guilds.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(guilds_dict, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    
    await ctx.send(f'Sent welcome channel for {ctx.message.guild.name} to {channel.name}')


# Optional:
# So if your bot leaves a guild, the guild is removed from the dict
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)

    guilds_dict.pop(guild.id)
    with open('guilds.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(guilds_dict, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```