# Welcome Message not sending to correct server. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

So, I am using this code below to send welcome & leave messages to my server.

I am going to provide an example of this error.

I have Server 1 (My main server I set the bot up on)
And then I have Server 2.

When I added my bot to Server 2, and invited a profile. It sent the welcome message to Server 1 rather than server 2.

What would I need to do with my code to make it so that when people join Server 2, it sends a welcome message to Server 2 instead of Server 1?

I realize that my Welcome & leave client events run off of the channel ID of Server 1 which is why when someone joins server 2, it sends a notification to server 1. If I wanted to let other servers use my bot, how could I make it to where the code grabs the channel ID of the server that it is being used in, instead of the notifications going all to one server?

I hope that this made sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

````
@client.event                                                                                                                                       #
async def on_member_join(member):                                                                                                                   #
    guild = client.get_guild(919401083057618945)                                                                                                    #
    channel = guild.get_channel(919401083711934536)                                                                                                 #
    await channel.send(f'**Welcome to the server {member.mention} ! :partying_face:**')                                                             #
    await member.send(f'**Welcome to the {guild.name} server, {member.name}! :partying_face:**')                                                    #
                                                                                                                                                    #
# (Notifies a member left)                                                                                                                          #
@client.event                                                                                                                                       #
async def on_member_remove(member):                                                                                                                 #
    guild = client.get_guild(919401083057618945)                                                                                                    #
    channel = guild.get_channel(919401083711934536)                                                                                                 #
    await channel.send(f'**{member.mention} Has left the server! :cry:**')```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Does the channel that you are sending to in Server 2 have a specific name? Do you want to store the id of a specific set channel?

Comment: Hi Bagle, thank you for the welcome! Server 2 does have a specific name. But I am looking for a code fix that would allow for the welcome & leave events to recognize what channel the code is being executed in, and then send the output to that server. So for example if I gave my bot invite link to someone cause they want to moderate their server with my bot. Any time someone joins or leaves that other persons server, it's going to send the notification to my discord server instead of their own.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Please do note that `on_member_join` and `on_member_remove` are not channel specific, but rather **server** specific. I still have another question though: when a user joins _Server 2_, where should the bot send its welcome message?

Comment: If a player were to join server two, the bot should should a message through server two. But I don't want to have to always change the channel ID in the code to make it to where the messages send in the correct server. Because if other people use my bot, then that would not be possible to have the bot set to all the different channel ID's

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I've submitted, I provided two possible options for you to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, so I will give you two of the possible options you should choose to do.

**Option 1** involves the [`discord.utils`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20textchannel#utility-functions) import. This import allows you to quickly and easily find a channel with a specific name, such as 'welcome' or 'join-and-leave'. While this is a quick and easy method, it does not allow the administrators or mods of other servers to change the channel name without this join function breaking. Do view the code below:

```py
import discord.utils # I recommend placing this with your other imports
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='welcome')
    await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}!")
```

**Option 2** makes use of `json`, which is good when starting out on a welcome bot or the likes. There are multiple questions on doing something like this. Here are some links to help you with this option:

- [How to set a welcome channel discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64772835/14420546) - SO
- [Discord.py welcome message for multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667213/discord-py-welcome-message-for-multiple-servers) - SO

Comment: My apologies for the late follow up, but this  worked perfectly like I had hoped. I appreciate it Bagle!